# I want to implement drag and drop functionality for textarea using CDK in angular 2 but it is not working properly

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, angular-cdk

I have display-text-area.component.html file which looks like

```
<textarea [ngStyle]="{'position':'absolute','z-index':1000,'left':jsonRef[selection].props.left+'px','top':jsonRef[selection].props.top+'px','width':jsonRef[selection].props.width+'px','height':jsonRef[selection].props.height+'px'}" [(ngModel)]="answer" draggable="true" id="0" cdkDrag (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
(cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)"
(cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)"
 ></textarea>
```

and for this file I have display-text-area.component.ts file which looks like

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragEnd, CdkDragStart, CdkDragMove, CdkDragExit, CdkDragEnter } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'pdf-DispplayTextArea',
  templateUrl: './display-text-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-text-area.component.scss']
})
export class DisplayTextAreaComponent implements OnInit{
  jsonRef: any[] = [];
  componentsRefs: any[] = [];
  selection: number;
  answer = '';
  constructor(  ) {
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  init(selection: any, jsonGroup: any, componentsRefs: any) {
    this.selection = selection.selection;
    this.jsonRef = jsonGroup;
    this.componentsRefs = componentsRefs;
  }

  dragStarted(event: CdkDragStart) {
  }

  dragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd) {
  }

  dragMoved(event: CdkDragMove) {
    console.log(event.pointerPosition.x + ' ' + event.pointerPosition.y);
    this.jsonRef[this.selection].props.left = event.pointerPosition.x;
    this.jsonRef[this.selection].props.top = event.pointerPosition.y;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.jsonRef));
   }
}
```

Now in html file jsonRef is JSON object and selection is basically used for the index so how textarea should be displayed that is depened on the value of left and top which is stored in the jsonRef. Now onDragMoved I am updating value of left and stored in the jsonRef by event.pointerPosition.x and event.pointerPosition.y so as jsonRef is updating our textarea should also displayed like that but on dragEnded method written in .ts file textArea is placed far away from pointer or cursor of which we have stored the value in jsonRef. So how can I solve this type of problem? I want to place the textarea on the position of cursor.

Thanks in advance.